# Applications of Hafnians

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

I am learning about Hafnians but I am struggling to find real-world applications of them. I understand the applications of determinants, permanents, and even pfaffians but I am at a loss for Hafnians. I know they can be used in nonbipartite graph matching but where would this be useful in the real world?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Googlin for it, there seems to be interest of physicists. [From Irrational to Non-Unitary: on the Haffnian and Haldane-Rezayi wave functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4978),   [pFfaffian, Gaffnian and Haffnian states : Quantum Computations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253658588_pFfaffian_Gaffnian_and_Haffnian_states_Quantum_Computations),   [Pseudopotentials and Quantum Hall States: Pfaffian,Gaffnian, Haffnian](http://online.kitp.ucsb.edu/online/qubit06/simon/), ...

Comment: Hafnian, with my f. Might help googling it :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg, "With my f"?!? :)  This could graduate to "an internet meme", surely !?! :)

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how I managed to misspell "one" as "my". But who am I to smother a meme in birth!

Comment: @darijgrinberg, you have my 'f'!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQyAR4EYJU#t=0m9s

Answer (score 5):

In the context of the [fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect), the ground state wave function $\Psi$ of electrons in a two-dimensional layer (coordinates $z_n=x_n+iy_n$, $n=1,2,\ldots$) in a strong perpendicular magnetic field can, for certain electron densities, be described by a Hafnian, see [From Irrational to Non-Unitary: on the Haffnian and Haldane-Rezayi wave functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4978) (2011):

$$\Psi(z_1,z_2,\ldots)={\rm Hf}\,(1/(z_i-z_j)^2)\prod_{i<j}(z_i-z_j)^2$$

A different application is to spin liquids, see pages 37 and following of [Physics of Resonating Valence Bond Spin Liquids](http://openscholarship.wustl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2163&context=etd) (2013).

---

Incidentally, most physics papers I have seen write *Haffnian*, [mistakenly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnian), with two f's, probably confused by *Pfaffian*.

Comment: And Pfaffnian is itself a confusion for Pfaffian.  :-)  All we know for sure is that the one 'f' in 'Hafnian' is [@darijgrinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273324/applications-of-hafnians#comment676533_273324)'s.

Comment: I think I should start collecting royalties...

Comment: Thanks @CarloBeenakker, I'm glad to know I'm not the only one who makes the Hafnian spelling mistake. As I commented on Zurab's post, I would love to learn about some non-quantum related applications for Hafnians (ie potentially marketable).

Answer (score 5):

In fact Hafnians were introduced by Eduardo Caianiello for a "real-world application", namely to simplify calculations in renormalized quantum field theory. As he writes,

> Fermi and Bose statistics require, respectively, the definition and study of pfaffians and determinants, and of hafnians and permanents: any expectation value of any product of free Fermi fields is in fact a pfaffian (which often, as we shall see, reduces to a determinant, e.g., in the Fredholm case and in electrodynamics); of Bose fields, a hafnian (which often reduces to a permanent). Tremendous simplifications are trivially seen to occur if we start with some preliminary (and quite elementary) mathematical considerations concerning these objects and their main properties.

See his book "Combinatorics and Renormalization in Quantum Field Theory" [https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Renormalization-Quantum-Frontiers-Physics/dp/0805316450](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805316450)

Interestingly, "The "Hafnian" denomination was coined by Caianiello to mark the fruitful period of stay in Copenhagen (Hafnia in Latin)" - see p.98 in the book " Imagination and Rigor: Essays on Eduardo R. Caianiello's Scientific Heritage" https://books.google.ru/books?id=K3xBKR2HiT8C

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zurab Silagadze. I know this is a "real-world application", but I would love to learn about the applications that do not relate directly to quantum mechanics. For instance, Pfaffians have some interesting applications such as perfect matchings (useful for chemistry), and calculating partition functions for various ML problems. To your knowledge, is there anything like that where hafnians provide a significant lift to potentially marketable problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For an application of hafnians in chemistry see http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci00008a016 (Topological organic chemistry. 5. Graph theory, matrix hafnians and pfaffians, and topological indexes of alkanes). Some multiple integrals are expressed via hafnians (Wick-Isserlis formula): https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204026 (Pfaffian and hafnian identities in shuffle algebras).  Some application of this can be found in https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/1.G002217 (Probabilistic Optical and Radar Initial Orbit Determination).